# A menu to drag around the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a menu which can be dragged around on the webpage.

Im trying to make a div, which says menu. when you click the menu a new div appears on top with a links and a hide button to go back to close the div again.

I've wrapped both div's in another div which I've made draggable, but the div's doesn't respond to being dragged.

When I inspect the menu I can see that the dragfunction is responding. In Inspector I can see the divs position changing but the div is not changing.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
#div.drag {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_drag">
  <div id="mydivheader">
 <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display='';return false;" href="">Menu</a>

 <div id="div_name2">

                              <a href="firstyear.html">+2018</a>
                              <br></br>
                              <a href="secondyear.html">+2017</a>
                              <br></br>
                              <a href="thirdyear.html">+2016</a>
                              <br></br>
                              <a href="fourthyear.html">+2015</a>
                              <br></br>

                              <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display='none';return false;" href="" 
                              >hide</a>
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
  
 <script>  
dragElement(document.getElementById(("div_drag")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
  
  </script>
```

Comment: I think the css for the div with id "div_drag" has a spelling mistake, you have written "#div.drag" which will look for a div with id "div" and a class "drag"

Comment: that worked! Just a spelling mistake. My bad!

Comment: No worries :) happens to all of us!